# why can loop index run out of loop bound

Tags: c++, c

Recently, I ran into a problem of iterations running out of loop bound. 
By logging, I found that the loop index cannot be bounded by the loop bound.

After further debugging, I have figured out that it was because an out-of-range write to `cross_parray`  occured somewhere before the code snippet attached following:

```
cv::Point2f cross_parray[8];
int cross_points_num = 0;
int j;

// ...

for(j = 0; j < cross_points_num; j++)
{
  printf("%d   Cross[%d]: %f %f\n", cross_points_num, j, cross_parray[j].x, cross_parray[j].y);
}
```

Here is the outputs by the above `printf`:

```
9   Cross[1718]: 239764258816.000000 0.049635
9   Cross[1719]: 56350172250112.000000 3277795840.000000
9   Cross[1720]: 245523097321472.000000 817.286072
9   Cross[1721]: 810850240.000000 0.000000
9   Cross[1722]: 4630804223985380483294822400.000000 17845644235931175201275904.000000
9   Cross[1723]: 279783113978270150157139968.000000 217149087997375045783066247168.000000
9   Cross[1724]: 16965729398885974016.000000 75876376993756550538537486778368.000000
9   Cross[1725]: 1125715943805045169979392.000000 257558259045784092672.000000
9   Cross[1726]: 71920725395007019893418622976.000000 263079777742056587264.000000
9   Cross[1727]: 18063601952671647256054595584.000000 17857709399654295200260188798976.000000
9   Cross[1728]: 286724012145286700981684214431744.000000 0.000000
9   Cross[1729]: 1157838373559229814725935104.000000 261926873829635784704.000000
9   Cross[1730]: 0.000000 0.000000
9   Cross[1731]: 0.000000 0.000000
```

Why an out-of-range error would cause such a weird execution that loop index run out of loop bound?

Comment: Modifying an array with an out of bounds index results in undefined behaviour. One possible manifestation of undefined bahaviour is modifying another unrelated variable.

Comment: ... also it would be interesting to know the value of `cross_points_num` just before the for loop.

Comment: @ Jabberwocky  it was also 9.

Comment: In the code section you don't show (`// ...`), `cross_points_num` becomes 9 at some point but it should become 7 at most. Debug this first. Also in that code section there may be other problems you're not aware of (and nor are we obviously) that can cause undefined bahaviour. Without seeing that code we can't help much. Check for out of bounds array access and you'll probably quickly find the problem

Comment: wrong, Jabberwocky, just wrong.

Answer (score 4):

That's probably because cross_points_num  is declared right after cross_parray; they are located in neighboring memory areas, so writing into cross_parray[8] (which is out of bounds for that particular array) is equivalent to writing at the location of cross_points_num.

If cross_parray was a notebook, writing beyond the limit of the last page would be like writing on the desk itself.

Comment: If `cross_points_num` is overwritten by out-of-range write, why `printf` output `9` instead of a weird number? It seems that `cross_points_num` points to one place, but `printf` accesses another place.

Comment: It is almost impossible to tell. Once you have been writing data out of the bounds of the array, whatever happens next is called "undefined behavior". Anything can happen in these situations, and your program may even seem to behave normally, until it won't.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior

Answer (score 3):

Once undefined behaviour occured in your program all bets are off (aka you are in UB land). Writing out-of-bounds can in practice potentially overwrite another variable and lead to unpredictable result for anything that happens after the out-of-bounds access.

Answer (score 3):

Using the answer of Alexandre Vinçon, I think I have an idea on this - not sure if this happens actually, but thought to add it as value here.

`cross_points_num` seems to have value 9 at the time of the loop.
`cross_parray` though has only 8 elements, which means that, modifying the value of `cross_parray[8]` will access the 9th element of the array (for instance, in a loop - can easily happen, for instance while instantiating the array). If you modify that value at any point, you are actually modifying the value of the address outside the array, that follows the array.

By what Alexandre mentions, there is a high probability that `cross_points_num` is stored right after the array. In that case, while attempting to modify `cross_parray[8]`, there is a high change you are modifying that variable. And, since your floating points have very large values, you end up with an iteration outside the loop.

I suggest that you try setting the variable `cross_points_num` value to 8, and see if this works.

Side note: I can see you are printing 3 numbers, while passing 4 arguments to printf.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
const int cross_points_num = 8;
cv::Point2f cross_parray[cross_points_num];

....
```